# prime checking c++ function outputs numbers that aren't prime

Tags: c++

I am making a C++ program that allows you to input a number and checks if it is prime. But it says that numbers like 9, 15, and 21 are prime. Can I have some help?
It is quite confusing. Here is my function that checks if it is prime:

```
bool isPrime(int num) {

    int w = 2;

    while (w <= num) {

        if (w % num == 0) {
                return false;
        }
        else if (w < num){
            w = w + 1;
        }

        if (w == num) {
            w = 0;
            return true; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be `num % w`

Comment: This [guide by Eric Lippert](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) might be of some help.

Comment: Side note: you are checking *far* too many numbers; you can reduce by: `while(w*w < num)`. Then drop anything after the first if block, just leave `w = w + 1;` or shorter: `++w;` and place the `return true;` *after* the while loop. Only half of the code, but still doing the same...

Comment: A very easy way to further reduce unnecessary tests: check for % 2 in a separate if *before* the loop, then start with `w = 3` and do `w += 2` within the loop (there are ways to skip multiples of 3, 5, and others as well, but this won't be as simple as just skipping multiples of 2 any more...).

Comment: No need to check factors greater than the square root of the target number. If the number is *not* prime, it would be possible to factor it into two numbers (which, if multiplied, would yield the target number) and if either of those is larger than the square root of the target then multiplying those numbers would result in a number greater than the target. So, all possible factors *must be* less than or equal to the square root of the target if the target is prime and you can stop your search when your test number is larger than the square root.

Comment: See also [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An extra speed up to [solution of Aconcagua](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51468591/8344060) can be obtained when you realize that all primes bigger than 3 can be written as *6n+1* or *6n+5* for natural *n*. Or even further, all primes bigger than 5 can be written as *30n+m*, with *m* in *{1,7,11,13,17,19,23,29}*. This is what is called [Wheel factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_factorization).

This is simply understood as:

- Wheel factorization of *2* (cfr. Aconcagua): If *n* is not divisible by 2, then *n* is not divisible by any multiple of 2
- Wheel factorization of *6=2x3*: If *n* is not divisible by 2, then *n* is not divisible by any multiple of 2 and if *n* is not divisible by 3, then *n* is not divisible by any multiple of 3.
- Wheel factorization of *30=2x3x5*: See above

So implementing the Wheel factorization of 6, quickly gives:

```
if (num == 1)     return false;
if (num  < 4)     return true;
if (num % 2 == 0) return false;
if (num % 3 == 0) return false;
int w = 5;
while (w*w <= num)
{
    if(num % (w-2) == 0) return false;
    if(num % w     == 0) return false;
    w += 6;
}
return true;
```

This algorithm should run at 2/3rd the speed to the solution of Aconcagua.

**remark:** the wheel factorization of 30 would only give a minor speedup as it only eliminates the sequence *30n+25* which is also covered by the wheel factorization of 6 as *6*(5*n + 4)+1*.

**remark:** this still tests numbers which should not be tested, example (*w=25* while we already know that *w-2=5* is tested, ditto for 35,49,...)

If you want to go a bit more robust and use a bit of memory, you might be interested in the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Other useful information can be found here : [primes](/questions/tagged/primes)

Answer (score 2):

With the actual bug already spotted (`w % num` instead of `num % w`), just some additional hints:

Your code is far too complex!

```
while (w <= num)  // why <=? w == num is irrelevant, in worst
                  // case, it will lead to false negatives (num % num == 0)!
{
    if (num % w == 0) // (already fixed!)
    {
         return false;
    }
    else if (w < num)
    {
        w = w + 1;
    }

    if (w == num) // as you increment by 1, this will always be false unless
                  // previous test failed - so simply use else instead
    {
        w = 0;
        return true; 
    }
}
```

First step:

```
while (w < num)
{
    if (w % num == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    /*else*/ if (w < num) // however, this check is repeated in the while
                          // loop anyway; no need to do the work twice 
    {
        ++w; // shorter...
    }
    else
    {
        // w = 0; // obsolete, we will be destroyed afterwards anyway...
        return true; 
    }
}
```

Second step:

```
while (w < num)
{
    if (w % num == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    ++w; // at some point, will reach w == num and the loop won't be re-entered
}
// we did not leave the loop prematurely (-> non-prime), so we are prime:
return true;
```

Optimisations:

1. If `num == n * m` and `n` is greater than `sqrt(num)`, then `m` is smaller! So `n` will already be caught when m is checked, so you don't have to check values greater than the square root. This will exclude a huge range of numbers already.
2. If `n` does not devide `num`, then `k * m` won't either. For multiples of 2 it is just too simple not to profit from (whereas while still rather easy, it gets more complex considering multiples of 3, 5, ...).

Applying these:

```
if(num % 2 == 0)
    return false;
int w = 3;
while (w*w <= num)  // be aware that I had an error here in my comment
                    // to the question - cannot fix it any more, though...
{
    if(num % w == 0)
        return false;
    w += 2;
}
return true;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, as you can probably tell,  I am very new to c++.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want 
    `if(num % w == 0)`
not 
    `if(w % num == 0)`

Answer (score 0):

here this code might help`bool isPrime(int num)

```
int w = 2;

while (w <= num) {

    if (num % w == 0) {
            return false;
    }
    else if (w < num){
        w = w + 1;
    }

    if (w == num) {
        w = 0;
        return true; 
    }
}
```

`