# How can I improve my prime number program with Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm?

Tags: c++, primes

My program prints all prime numbers from this expression:

`((1 + sin(0.1*i))*k) + 1, i = 1, 2, ..., N.`

> Input Format:
>
> No more than 100 examples. Every example has 2 positive integers on the same line.
>
> Output Format:
>
> Print each number on a separate line.
>
> Sample Input:
>
> 4 10
>
> 500 100
>
> Sample Output:
>
> 5
>
> 17

But my algorithm is not efficient enough. How can I add Sieve of Eratosthenes so it can be efficient enough to not print "Terminated due to timeout".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main() {
long long k, n;
int j;
    while (cin >> k >> n) {
    if (n>1000 && k>1000000000000000000) continue;

    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        int res = ((1 + sin(0.1*i)) * k) + 1;
        for (j = 2; j < res; j++) {
            if (res % j == 0) break;
        }
        if (j == res) count++;
    }
    cout << count << endl;

}
system("pause");
```

Comment: I think you should migrate your question in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: am I understanding correctly that you need to count the number of primes among the numbers `r=((1+sin(0.1*i))*k)+1` for `i=1..n` and for a set of up to 100 pairs `(n,k)`?

Comment: `r` will be the number result from the expression. Then check it if it's a prime, Ignore the set of up to 100 pairs.

Comment: In your code, how large is `res` typically?

Comment: From the Sample input  `4 10`, the `res` numbers will be `5 5 6 6 6 7 7 7 8 8` Count will be then 5

Comment: Should not `res` be a `long long`?

Comment: @Damien It will still output "Terminated due to timeout"

Comment: Before trying to improve the speed, we have to be sure that the programme provides the correct output. This is why I mentioned this issue. With a large `k` and `int` you can get overflow

Comment: Since sin(x) is, in general, not an integer, it must be specified what to do about non-integral sin(x). Some options are floor, ceiling, truncate toward 0, and round (with rounding rules). Care is needed, since sin() takes on negative values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can improve your speed by 10x simply by doing a better job with your trial division.  You're testing all integers from 2 to `res` instead of treating 2 as a special case and testing just odd numbers from 3 to the square root of `res`:

```
// k <= 10^3, n <= 10^9

int main() {
    unsigned k;
    unsigned long long n;

    while (cin >> k >> n) {

        unsigned count = 0;

        for (unsigned long long i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            unsigned long long j, res = (1 + sin(0.1 * i)) * k + 1;

            bool is_prime = true;

            if (res <= 2 || res % 2 == 0) {
                is_prime = (res == 2);
            } else {
                for (j = 3; j * j <= res; j += 2) {
                    if (res % j == 0) {
                        is_prime = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (is_prime) {
                count++;
            }
        }

    cout << count << endl;
    }
}
```

Though k = 500 and n = 500000000 is still going to take forty seconds or so.

Comment: You code works with `(k <= 10^18, N <= 10^3)` but not with `(k <= 10^3, N <= 10^9)`. I changed `n` to `long long` but it still prints "Terminated due to timeout".

Comment: @Erj, what is the source for the limits?  Please provide a link.  I based them on what your code tested, how would I know otherwise?

Comment: `k <= 10^3, N <= 10^9`. The other stuff is the same.

Comment: @Erj, I've reworked the code with the revised (reversed) limits.  I also added a timing example as you approach those limits.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I added a 3rd mean to improve efficiency
EDIT2: Added an explanation why Sieve should not be the solution and some trigonometry relations. Moreover, I added a note on the history of the question

Your problem is not to count all the prime numbers in a given range, but only those which are generated by your function.

Therefore, I don't think that the Sieve of Eratosthenes is the solution for this particular exercise, for the following reason: `n` is always rather small while `k` can be very large. If `k`is very large, then the Sieve algorithm would have to generate a huge number of prime numbers, for finally use it for a small number of candidates.

You can improve the efficiency of you program by three means:

- Avoid calculating `sin(.)` every time. You can use trigonometric relations for example. Moreover, first time you calculate these values, store them in an array and reuse these values. Calculation of `sin()`is very time consuming
- In your test to check if a number is prime, limit the search to `sqrt(res)`. Moreover, consider make the test with odd `j` only, plus `2`
- If a candidate `res` is equal to the previous one, avoid redoing the test

**A few trigonometry**
If c = cos(0.1) and s = sin(0.1), you can use the relations :

- `sin (0.1(i+1)) = s*cos (0.1*i) + c*sin(0.1*i))`
- `cos (0.1(i+1)) = c*cos (0.1*i) - s*sin(0.1*i))`

If `n` were large, it should be necessary to recalculate the `sin()` by the function regularly to avoid too much rounding error calculation. But it should not be the case here as `n` is always rather small.

However, as I mentioned, it is better to use only the "memorization" trick in a first step and check if it is enough.

*A note on the history of this question and why this answer:*

Recently, this site received several questions " how to improve my program, to count number of prime numbers generated by this `k*sin()` function ..." To my knowledge, these questions were all closed as duplicate, under the reason that the Sieve is the solution and was explained in a previous similar (but slightly different) question. Now, the same question reappeared under a slightly different form "How can I insert the Sieve algorithm in this program ... (with k*sin() again)". And then I realised that the Sieve is not the solution. It is not a criticism to previous closes as I made the same mistake in the understanding on the question. However, I think it is time to propose a new solution, even it is does not match the new question perfectly

Comment: The thing is, I have to use sin with the expression `((1 + sin(0.1*i))*k) + 1`

Comment: I know. But using trigonometric functions, you can calculate `sin(0.1 * (i+1))` from `sin(0.1 * i)`. The problem is not to avoid calculation of the sinus values, but to avoid call of `sin(.)` function as much as possible

Comment: Anyway, in a first step, you can try using the memorization trick and see what gain you get

Comment: I don't understand how I can avoid `sin(.)` every time.

Answer (score 1):

When you make use of a simple [Wheel factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_factorization), you can obtain a very nice speedup of your code. Wheel factorization of order 2 makes use of the fact that all primes bigger than 3 can be written as *6n+1* or *6n+5* for natural *n*. This means that you only have to do 2 divisions per 6 numbers. Or even further, all primes bigger than 5 can be written as *30n+m*, with *m* in *{1,7,11,13,17,19,23,29}*. ( 8 divisions per 30 numbers).

Using this simple principle, you can write the following function to test your primes (wheel {2,3}):

```
bool isPrime(long long num) {
  if (num == 1)     return false;   // 1 is not prime
  if (num  < 4)     return true;    // 2 and 3 are prime
  if (num % 2 == 0) return false;   // divisible by 2
  if (num % 3 == 0) return false;   // divisible by 3
  int w = 5;
  while (w*w <= num) {
      if(num % w     == 0) return false; // not prime
      if(num % (w+2) == 0) return false; // not prime
      w += 6;
  }
  return true;                     // must be prime
}
```

You can adapt the above for the wheel {2,3,5}. This function can be used in the main program as:

```
int main() {
  long long k, n;

  while (cin >> k >> n) {
    if (n>1000 && k>1000000000000000000) continue;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      long long res = ((1 + sin(0.1*i)) * k) + 1;
      if (isPrime(res)) { count++; }
    }
    cout << count << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

A simple timing gives me for the original code (`g++ prime.cpp`)

```
 % time echo "6000 100000000" | ./a.out 
 12999811
 echo "6000 100000000"  0.00s user 0.00s system 48% cpu 0.002 total
 ./a.out  209.66s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 3:29.70 total
```

while the optimized version gives me

```
% time echo "6000 100000000" | ./a.out                                                                                                                                                                                                        
12999811
echo "6000 100000000"  0.00s user 0.00s system 51% cpu 0.002 total
./a.out  10.12s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 10.124 total
```

Other improvements can be made but might have minor effects:

1. precompute your sine-table `sin(0.1*i)` for `i` from 0 to 1000. This will avoid recomputing those sines over and over. This however, has a minor impact as most time is wasted on the primetest.
2. Checking if `res(i) == res(i+1)`: this has barely any impact as, depending on `n` and `k` most consecutive `res` are not equal.
3. Use a lookup table, might be handier, this does have an impact.

**original answer:**

My suggestion is the following:

1. Precompute your sinetable `sin(0.1*i)` for `i` from 0 to 1000. This will avoid recomputing those sines over and over. Also, do it smart (see point 3)
2. Find the largest possible value of `res` which is `res_max=(2*k)+1`
3. Find all primes for `res_max` using the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). Also, realize that all primes bigger than 3 can be written as *6n+1* or *6n+5* for natural *n*. Or even further, all primes bigger than 5 can be written as *30n+m*, with *m* in *{1,7,11,13,17,19,23,29}*. This is what is called [Wheel factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_factorization). So do not bother checking any other number. (a tiny bit more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51480542/8344060))
4. Have a lookup table that states if a number is a prime.
5. Do all your looping over the lookup table.

Comment: For large `k` and small `n`, this may still be inefficient, since most entries in the lookup table for primes are never used. Instead of that lookup table and sieve of Eratosthenes, you may use a [primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test), though this may be too advanced for your problem.

Comment: I made similar function to yours, but it still gives "Terminated due to timeout".

Comment: @Erj can you give me the input for that timeout?

Comment: @kvantour its hidden from hackerrank.

Comment: @cdlane's program works. Thanks for everyone that helped.

Comment: @Erj, could you inform my why this did not work, or point me to the problem page?

Comment: @kvantour https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/cscb300-2018-t01/challenges This is the task. It's in Bulgarian. Let me know if you need translation. I can't tell why yours didn't work. My professor said he won't give any tips or hints. Edited: the problem is `2b`. You need to sign up before that.